# Localizando Objeto em uma List

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Tenho os seguintes objetos

```
    public class Passo {
      private Long id;
      private Date dataAtend;
      private Time horaRealizada;
      private Long idProfissionalRealizador;
      private String Descricao;
      /*getter & Setters*/  
    }

    public class Atendimento
    {
      private Long id;
      private Date dataAtend;
      private Long idPaciente;
      private Long idProfissionalResponsavel;
      private List<Passo> passos;

      /*getter & Setters*/ 
      public void addPasso(Passo passo){
        passos.add(passo)
      }

    }
```

e tenho uma lista de Atendimentos, onde tenho que localizar um atendimento por sua ID, nesta lista, e inserir mais Passos.
Algo tipo assim

```
    ...{
      List<Atendimento> atd = new ArrayList<Atendimento>();
      int idAtendimento;
      Passo passo;
      /* Trecho de codigo*/
      int index = atd.indexOf(atd.element.id = idAtendimento);
      if (index > 0 )
      {
        Atendimento(atd.get(index)).addPasso(passo);    
      }  
      else
      {
        Atendimento atend =util.GetAtendimento(idAtendimento);
        atend.addPasso(passo);
        atd.add(atend);
      }
    }
```

não posso sobrescrever o equals, pois ele ja está sobreescrito comparando todos os valores... =/

Comment: `Public Class Passo` - Você sabe que o `public` e o `class` deveriam ser com letra minúscula, né?

Comment: Corrigir, Victor. =)

Comment: Simplesmente fazer um `for` que percorre a lista em busca de um elemento que contenha o id desejado e retornar esse elemento ou então `null` caso não encontrado não resolve pra você?

Comment: Cara, não entendi o seu exemplo. O trecho de código que você deu não compila nem preenchendo o que falta de forma imaginativa, pois na linha `int index = atd.indexOf(atd.element.id = idAtendimento);` o `idAtendimento` é uma variável não inicializada. Além disso a atribuição dentro do parâmetro do `indexOf` me parece muito suspeita e confusa. Também, `Atendimento(atd.get(index))` também não compila porque `Atendimento` é uma classe, e não um método. Além disso, não dá para saber o que é `util.GetAtendimento`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso daqui não funciona?

```
private List<Atendimento> lista = new ArrayList<>();

private Atendimento buscarPorId(long id) {
    for (Atendimento a : lista) {
        if (a.getId().longValue() == id) return a;
    }
    return null;
}

private void adicionarPasso(long idAtendimento, Passo passo) {
    Atendimento a = buscarPorId(idAtendimento, lista);
    if (a == null) {
         a = fazerAlgumaCoisaQueCrieOuObtenhaOAtendimentoComEsteId(idAtendimento);
         lista.add(a);
    }
    a.addPasso(passo);
}
```

Outra ideia é usar um `Map` ao invés de um `List`, para evitar ter que percorrer a lista para procurar um elemento. Seria assim:

```
private Map<Long, Atendimento> map = new TreeMap<>();

private void adicionarPasso(long idAtendimento, Passo passo) {
    Atendimento a = map.get(idAtendimento);
    if (a == null) {
         a = fazerAlgumaCoisaQueCrieOuObtenhaOAtendimentoComEsteId(idAtendimento);
         map.put(idAtendimento, a);
    }
    a.addPasso(passo);
}
```

Se você precisar converter o `List` para `Map` em alguma ocasião, pode usar isso:

```
private static Map<Long, Atendente> mapear(List<Atendimento> lista) {
    Map<Long, Atendente> map = new TreeMap<>();
    for (Atendimento a : lista) {
         map.put(a.getId(), a);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Se precisar converter o `Map` para um `List`:

```
List<Atendimento> lista = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
```

Ou então, se preferir converter sem precisar criar cópia defensiva, você também pode usar assim:

```
Collection<Atendimento> lista = map.values();
```

Answer (score 0):

Dê uma olhada [nesse material](http://blog.caelum.com.br/ordenando-colecoes-com-comparable-e-comparator/) sobre `Comparator` e `Comparable`, da Caelum. Com ele você pode definir o atributo `id` do seu objeto como parâmetro para a comparação.

Espero que seja de ajuda o material (foi a minha referência quando precisei desse tipo de técnica =D)

Abraço

Comment: o problema é que não quero ordenar, mas obter a classe.
mas no fim deste artigo tem um link para outro que me parece mais interessante. acho que ele é me mais util

Comment: É só você criar um método que vá utilizar o `compareTo` e quando for igual, retornar o objeto selecionado na comparação. Eu creio que dessa forma não te traga tanto trabalho na implementação.